# OPC UA Classes Add, Delete and Modify at Runtime

Tags: opc-ua, opc, node-opcua

I'm working on OPC UA Server And trying to create a feature of classes and instances on the addressSpace OnRunTime. I have a problem in modifying OPC UA Deleting or adding Classes on Runtime.

I'm actually generating classes with UA ModelCompiler adding them to my UA server project and adding a nodemanager to load the predefined nodes and instances.

I didn't find a way so when I change a class in the ModelDesinger.xml it will be changed automatically on my project without regenerating them all with the UA ModelCompiler.

Comment: It's worth noting that contributors who persist in conducting pointless edit wars on deleted questions may acquire downvotes on their current questions. It is a good rule of thumb on Stack Overflow that if you encounter the tail of a dragon, it is not worth a pull. 